# WordPress Admin Dashboard Does Not Display Correctly

Tags: errors

I download the wordpress files via ftp software ,after that I install the wordpress , then when I try to access the dashboard display doesn't work correctly , it is shown as links without css

so can anyone help me please

[image]

Comment: Where are you downloading WordPress from? Seems like you are installing a copy from a working site and the files are not loading locally. Probably the site is using SSL and your local copy doesn't allow SSL connections...

Try showing your console errors for more details.

Comment: I download the files from the wordpress.org , it is not a download issue but I think the error is from hosting provider it seems like proxy issue

Comment: Show me the console errors with CMD + Shift + I or F12 using Chrome

Comment: wp-admin wp-core-ui js  index-php auto-fold admin-bar branch-5 version-5-0-2 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us no-svg customize-support

Comment: These are not errors. Try to make a screenshot from the errors from the console or copy/paste them. If you can't do that I won't be able to help you ;D. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/

Comment: :D 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1KsbGunuheDTjYXrRp6uSjNWf1W1hAblZhEbp40Kn6pc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Ok, seems a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1 Try to find that error with Google as there are a lot of results...

Comment: You can fix the wp-admin css break by increasing "PHP Max Input Vars" value from 1000 to 2000 but make sure that there is no comma between the values i.e 2,000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems a duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916987/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-load-scripts-php1, Try to find that error with Google as there are a lot of results

You can also try editing your wp-config.php file ( it is located on the root folder of your installation ) and right before the lines that say:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

and add this

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

This will tell WordPress to load each script on it’s own instead of combining them. This might be caused due to some faulty or outdated plugin .js that overrides something else when it is concatenated.

Source: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/uncaught-syntaxerror-invalid-or-unexpected-token-load-scripts-php/

If that doesn't fix your problem, try to deactivate all plugins moving them to a temp folder via FTP or renaming the plugins folder to sth like plugins_old. Maybe one of them is causing the issue here...

Comment: it is working after I add "define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);"
thank you :)

Comment: This could also occur if you have low diskspace. Worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you for this!